# How to calculate mixing of two ratios to get desired ratio?

Tags: ratio

For the purpose of this example lets say I have two ingredients:

1. water ($100\%$)
2. a chocolate mix ($80\%$ chocolate, $20\%$ water)

The goal is to mix them together to create a mix that is exactly $50\%$ water and $50\%$ chocolate.

How can I calculate exactly how much of the 2 ingredients to combine to create 500ml without waste?

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea how to solve this. Thats why I posted here.

Answer (score 2):

If you take $s$ liters (or quarts, etc.) number 1, and $(1-s)$ liters of #2, you'll end up with $1$ liter of mix. That liter will contain
$$
(1-s)  0.8 = 0.8 - 0.8s
$$
liters of chocolate; you want that to be $0.5$ liters. So set
\begin{align}
0.8 - 0.8s &= 0.5 \\
-0.8s &= -0.3 \\
s &= \frac{-0.3}{-0.8} = \frac{3}{8}
\end{align}
So: take 3/8 pure water, and 5/8 chocolate mix.

If you have, say, 7 liters of the 80% mix (what I've called "#2"), you'll need $\frac{3}{5} \times 7$ of the water to make your 50-50 mix.

In short: let's say the amount of chocolate mix that you have (measured in cups, gallons, liters, whatever) is $A$. You'll need to add $0.6 \times A$ of water to it. You'll end up with $1.6 \times A$ of mix.

For instance, if you have 9 cups of the 80% mix, you'll need to add $0.6 \times 9 = 5.4 cups$ of water to it to get to a 50% mix; when you're done, you'll have the original 9 cups of mix plus 5.4 cups of water to get 14.4 cups of mix, whic is $1.6 \times 9$.

(I got $s$ and $1-s$ screwed up in my earlier response, which I've now fixed up.)

**Final Edit**

Now that the problem's been clarified -- you want to get some amount $C$ of final 50-50 mix -- the solution is this:

quantity of pure water: (3/8) * C

quantity of 80% choc:   (5/8) * C.

In your example where $C = 500$ml, you get

water: (3/8) * 500 = 187.5 ml

mix: (5/8) * 500 = 312.5 ml

Comment: It sounds like you know what your talking about. But sadly I don't. Could you explain perhaps in more layman terms? My English is excellent but I do not understand this. But thankyou for answering so quickly.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify I want to know how to calculate the exact quantity of water i should add. Maybe your answer contains that info in math language but I can't decipher it.

Comment: I've added somewhat more detail; hope that helps.

Comment: This is all very well if you know how much of  A you have and want to use it all. I should have pointed out that that is not the case. Sorry. The other peice of the puzzle is that I know how much of the final mix I want, lets say 500ml. I want to add the 2 ingredients to create that amount without waste. So to rephrase: How can I calculate exactly how much of the 2 ingredients to combine to create 500ml?  I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, that you have $x$ liters of the mixture. Then you have $0,2x$ water. Now you add $y$ liters of pure water. The sum of these two liquids has to have the average water proportion. It is $0.5\cdot (x+y)$

Thus the equation is $0.2x+y=0.5x+0.5y$

Solve this equation for y. This gives you the amount of pure water, which you have to add-in relation to x.

Comment: Thanks. but i cant solve equations. I think this website is over my head. But really thankyou.

Comment: @pmatts Your are welcome. It´s a good idea to give response. I think the first two sentences you are able to understand, aren´t you ?. You have to say, from what point it is not comprehensible for you. Then I can give you further explanations.

Answer (score 0):

There are two related problems of this sort that come up, and it is worth distinguishing them carefully. They involve solving the same equations but with different givens.

Problem 1:

You have $V_2$ liters of mixture 2, which has concentration $0.8$, and you want to dilute it with $V_1$ liters of mixture 1, which has concentration $0$, in such a way that the result has concentration $0.5$. So here $V_2$ is given, $V_1$ is unknown, and you want

$$\frac{0.8V_2}{V_1+V_2}=0.5.$$
Solving this you find $0.5V_1=0.3V_2$ so $V_1=0.6V_2$.

Problem 2:

You have as much of mixtures 1 and 2 as is required, and you want a total volume of $V$ which has concentration $0.5$. So here $V$ is given and $V_1,V_2$ are both unknown. Then you want to solve the two equations

$$V_1+V_2=V \\
\frac{0.8V_2}{V_1+V_2}=0.5.$$

I will solve this case in detail. Using the first equation, replace $V_1+V_2$ by $V$ in the second equation:

$$\frac{0.8V_2}{V}=0.5.$$

Multiply both sides by $V$:

$$0.8V_2=0.5V.$$

Divide both sides by $0.8$:

$$V_2=\frac{5}{8} V.$$

Now substitute into the first equation to get $V_1=V-\frac{5}{8} V = \frac{3}{8} V.$

One thing that simplifies the situation in practice is that with these types of equations, $V_1,V_2$ will always be directly proportional to $V$, if all the other numbers are held constant. That means you can solve the problem for $V=1$ and then multiply by $V$. This is done in John Hughes' answer.

Comment: Thankyou Ian. I'm sure your right but i'm losing hope now. I'm a programmer and sometimes also use spreadsheets. I don't understand mathematical formulas like that. I guess I asked in the wrong place. I will drink a coffe and see if I can make sense of it enough to put some formulas into some cells so things work. Many thanks to everyone for trying to help. You've been awesome. But i have the feeling I will have to learn how to solve formulas to use this website.

Comment: @pmatts This is actually fairly basic algebra; I've expanded upon it in my edit.

Comment: ok i give up. I need a solution that works in a spreadsheet and i'll pay.

Comment: @pmatts Put the concentration of mixture 1 in A1, the concentration of mixture 2 in A2, the final concentration in A3, and the total volume in A4. Then the volume of mixture 1 is A4*(A3-A2)/(A1-A2) and the volume of mixture 2 is A4*(A1-A3)/(A1-A2). (Not sure why this is any better than the symbolic explanation I gave before, but if it helps, it helps...)

Comment: Ian you are great. It most certainly helps. I did some algebra at school but I clearly wasn't listening. Thankyou so much.